# Checkbox tkinter select between two option

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I am writing a small program in Python using Tkinter.The problem is that checkbox can not auto deselect when I choose another option. It still allows to select both options.

```
C1 = Checkbutton(root, text="Full Screen", variable=CheckVar1,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,height=5, width=20).pack side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=2)
C2 = Checkbutton(root, text="Area", variable=CheckVar2,onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, width=20).pack(side=RIGHT,pady=5, padx=5)
if CheckVar1.get():
   CheckVar2.set(0)[enter image description here][1]
    
elif CheckVar2.get():
   CheckVar1.set(0)
else:
   messagebox.showerror('Tk', 'Something went wrong!')
```

Comment: You should be using radiobutton then.

Comment: It can be by setting different `onvalue` for the checkbuttons and use same tkinter variable for them.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks, I have just tried your way and it's really useful

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to use the Radiobutton instead.

This widget implements a multiple-choice button, which is a way to offer many possible selections to the user and lets user choose only one of them.

In order to implement this functionality, each group of radiobuttons must be associated to the same variable and each one of the buttons must symbolize a single value. You can use the Tab key to switch from one radionbutton to another.

Here's an example of an implementation using Radiobutton:

```
from Tkinter import *

def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection)

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
R1.pack( anchor = W )

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
R2.pack( anchor = W )

R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=sel)
R3.pack( anchor = W)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Hopoe this is helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot. This way really helps me fix my problem